# Download google trends data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, google-trends

I am trying to download google trends data using MATLAB. However, when I run the following command, I am not able to download the data.

```
!"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?q=MSFT&geo=US&content=1&export=1&graph=all_csv
```

However, when I paste the URL part into google chrome it will download. How can I get this to work in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the *data* in MATLAB. To do this, it is best to not make a system call to Google Chrome, but rather to use the tools integrated within MATLAB to do this such as [`websave`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/websave.html).

So you'd want to do something like:

```
filename = websave('filename.csv', 'http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?q=msft&geo=us&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1')
```

That being said, this may be a little tricky because Google likely requires authentication for access to that page so you would need to use the [`weboptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/websave.html#input_argument_options) input to provide the necessary credentials.